# How to issue apt-get update?

Tags: 16.04, apt

After running the command `sudo apt-get update`

I got the following error:

```
W: GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
W: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a repository that has a security certificate problem.  Until the repo maintainers fix that, the only way you'll be able to complete your update is to disable that repository.  If it's only the two, that shouldn't be a big deal, and the issue should be temporary -- the repo maintainers should be notified every time their repo fails a security check.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Key from 'curl -s http://nsolid-deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/NODESOURCE-NSOLID-GPG-SIGNING-KEY'

To fix that error you have to import that key for the repository you are using. To import the key for your repository, run the following command

```
curl -s http://nsolid-deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/NODESOURCE-NSOLID-GPG-SIGNING-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: "no key on the keyring" produces a different error from "repository not signed."  Your answer will fix the former, for that repository (though there remains the issue of whether you should trust the repo), but doesn't address "repository not signed".